# Why my \verb-ish command is not escaped inside \VerbatimEnvironment?

Tags: fancyvrb

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{v}{\texttt{#1}}
\catcode`\|\active
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\|\active\def|{\foo|}}
\catcode`\| 12 %
\newenvironment{vvv}
  {\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{VerbatimOut}{a.txt}}
  {\end{VerbatimOut}}
\begin{document}
\begin{vvv}
hello, |world|!
\end{vvv}
\end{document}
```

It doesn't compile:

```
Runaway text?
hello, \foo \foo \foo \foo \foo \foo \foo \foo \foo \foo \foo \foo \foo \ETC.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
|->\foo
        |
l.20 hello, |world|!
```

What's wrong? I expect my `vvv` environment to save `hello, |world|!` to the file `a.txt`. Maybe there is an approach better than `\VerbatimEnvironment`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{v}{\texttt{#1}}
\catcode`\|\active
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\|\active\def|{\foo|}}
\catcode`\| 12 %
\newenvironment{vvv}
  {\catcode`\|=12 \VerbatimEnvironment\begin{VerbatimOut}{a.txt}}
  {\end{VerbatimOut}}
\begin{document}
\begin{vvv}
hello, |world|!
\end{vvv}
\end{document}
```